# In what espace lives $\delta(x-y)$?

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta

> A [Dirac distribution](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Dirac+distribution) or Dirac $\delta$-distribution $\delta(p)$ is the distribution that is given by evaluating a function at a point $p$.

That is, the Dirac $\delta(p)$ function is the distribution defined by $$\langle\delta(p),\phi \rangle=\phi(p)$$

Suppose we want to write

$$\int\phi(x)\phi(x)dx=\int\int_0^1\delta(
x-y)\phi(x)\phi(y)dxdy$$

How should we define $\delta(
x-y)$?

In this page [Free quantum fields](https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/newideaofquantumfieldtheory-freequantumfields/) on example 14.4 they have
$\delta(
x-y) \in \Gamma'(E \boxtimes E)$ where  $\Gamma'(E \boxtimes E)$ is the dual of the space of section of the bundle  $\Gamma(E \boxtimes E)$  and
And $E$ is the real line bundle

Answer (score 2):

Define $\delta(x-y)$ for $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$ as the distribution on $\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n$ such that
$$
\langle \delta(x-y), \varphi(x, y) \rangle = \int \varphi(t, t) \, dt
$$
for every test function $\varphi.$